# get location of folder content stored on another server web

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, directory

I'm working on an ASP MVC 4 application, I need to get some documents stored in a directory in another web server by getting their path and store it in my application or copy it's content and use it. Is there any way to do this ? I think I can use `Server.MapPath("")` but I don't know how. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath will only work to access files or directories which are accessible from the server which the application is hosted from. If the other web server is on the same network then that should be fine.

Otherwise, you could download the files from another web server if you have the requisite permissions, either by HTTP or FTP.

Comment: Yes I've the requisite permissions to access but I need to do this from my application

Answer (score 0):

If you can access those web server using local network, just add that network location as virtual folder to your IIS and use Server.MapPath